# How to get the element attribute type from XSD in python?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xsd, element

Is there a way possible to get element attribute type from xsd if xpath for the corresponding xml is provided. The xsd can also contain user-defined attribute as well as has complex type and simple type elements.
I did try lxml but found no success in it(Mostly because I could not implement it correctly). 
I am relatively new to python. 
Thank you for your help